# How to override Vertical Scroll behaviour in ListBox?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, scrollviewer

I am using a List box with wrappnael to hold a list of images in grid fashion. I am also using Mouse Drag Behaviors to drag and drop the items with in ListBox. But i am not able to drag an item vertically up or down because there is a vertical scrolling in the ListBox. How do i able to drag the item vertically also by not affecting the scrolling behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"></ListBox>
```

Hope its help.

Comment: if I disable scroll bar then i cant scroll through items.

Comment: @Shilpa try to disable when you start drag item, and enabled when all done.

Comment: I tried that but when i disable the scroll ListBox goes to its initial position does not stay in the place where we stopped dragging. When i scroll down and start dragging an element disabling the scrolling takes it to the initial place.

Comment: @Shilpa, try to experiment with VerticalScrollBarVisibility and ScrollIntoView, when you start drag.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the ability to select anything in the `ListBox` and don't want the ability to scroll you could always replace your `ListBox` control with an `ItemsControl`. Then you'd have no issues with scrolling at all.

Comment: No, I have to scroll through items in order to view the rest of them.